# Qt5, Coin3D and SoQt

Tags: c++, qt5, coin3d

I'm trying to work with Qt5, SoQt (Version 1.5.0) and Coin3D (3.1.3). I used instructions found on [this website](https://github.com/iat-cener/tonatiuh/wiki/Installing-Coin3D-For-Linux) to install Coin3D. I tried to install SoQt as well (Instructions found [here](https://github.com/iat-cener/tonatiuh/wiki/Installing-SoQt-For-Linux)). I had to change those export commands a little bit:

```
export COINDIR="/usr/local/share"
```

I tried four different versions of the export INCLUDE since i'm clueless about its purpose and i am not sure if this is the reason for the errors i'm getting:

```
export INCLUDE="/usr/local/include:/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore"
export INCLUDE="/usr/local/include:/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5"
export INCLUDE="/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtCore"
export INCLUDE="/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5"
```

This is where errormessages appear: (Shorter summary below)

```
checking for QT4... 
Could not gather the configure flags for Qt through pkg-config. Please
ensure that the qt pkg-config metadata .pc files, such as QtCore.pc,
exist on your system. In case the metadata .pc files are installed
into a non-default location verify that the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment
variable points to the correct directory.

Further details in how to set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
can be found in the pkg-config(1) man page.

checking whether the X11 miscellaneous utilities library is available... maybe
checking for cygpath... false
checking for moc... /usr/bin/moc
configure: WARNING: header file qglobal.h not found, can not compile Qtcode
configure: WARNING: QTDIR environment variable not set -- this might be an indication of a problem

Could not find any way to build against the Qt library. If you
are sure Qt is properly installed on your system, see the file
config.log to find out what went wrong.

One common way to solve this problem is to set up the environment
variable QTDIR to the base of the Qt installation directory. Or if it
was already set up, double check to see that it is pointing at the
correct directory.

Note that it is possible to override the combinations of Qt libraries
configure tries to link against by setting up the environment variable
CONFIG_QTLIBS. This might be necessary if you have installed the Qt
library in a manner that is not compatible with any of the known
configurations, for instance by changing the name of the library or
the Qt library having more dependencies on other libraries that we are
aware of.

If you for instance know the correct set of libraries to be qt304.lib,
qtmain.lib and gdi32.lib (this would be on an MSWindows system), then
set CONFIG_QTLIBS to the string ''-lqt304 -lqtmain -lgdi32'' before
re-running configure.

If you still can't get the configure script to detect the presence of
and how to use the Qt library, please mail the config.log file to
<coin-support@coin3d.org> and ask for help.

configure: error: aborting
```

I might be wrong but it seems like he is looking for Qt4 and not Qt5 because of

```
checking for QT4...
```

It also reads

```
configure: WARNING: header file qglobal.h not found, can not compile Qtcode
```

That's why i tried using qt5/QtCore instead of qt5 as path because there is a qglobal.h located within QtCore but it doesn't change anything.

Did anyone else face similar problems when setting up SoQt with Qt5 and can help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those releases are very old (2012). Please grab the latest source of Coin from the CMake brach [1], and SoQt from [2]. Build with CMake. Also see this discussion [3] regarding high DPI support.

[1] https://bitbucket.org/Coin3D/coin/branch/CMake
[2] https://bitbucket.org/Coin3D/soqt/branch/default
[3] https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/coin3d-discuss/ipkSH08iFNk

Comment: Thanks! It "kind of" works now. Program does start but it since it's maybe 10 years old there's just a black screen where graphics should be. Any idea where to start to make it work again? Seems like the best option would be to move away from Coin/SoQt...

Comment: I have had the black screen myself a while back, but it would render normally after resizing the window. But I use Quarter instead of SoQt, which has come along further.

Comment: Moving away from SoQt to Quarter might be the easiest and most attractive solution (although it should be possible to make SoQt work). Quarter comes with several examples which should work out of the box, you could check whether they do work. What is your platform/compiler?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu and GCC right now. Resizing the window sadly didn't work for me. We thought about using VTK since Coin/SoQt are very old by now and it seems like there isn't that much happening.